# Dynamically registered broadcast reciever doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, runtime, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to find out what is wrong here for a couple of hours. Why this broadcast reciever does not recieve the intent ?

```
static class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Got the intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    setContentView(mLayout);
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.testui.action");
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BReceiver(), intentFilter);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("com.example.testui.action");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

PS. I didn't define this reciever in a manifest file, because, strictly saying, it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to send broadcast this way:

```
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.testui.action"));
```

Comment: Yes, it did the trcik. Could you explain why it didn't work in my way ?

Comment: When you use explicit intent (that designate the target component by its name, `new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BReceiver.class)`) android is only looking through the components that was added to the AndroidManifest. As you said your receiver wasn't added. That why you should use implicit intent(that has only an action and a data but not a component name). [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) you can find more details how intent filters work.